# Not getting the pop up from App store for In-App-Purchase

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am working on application in which i am implementing In-App-Purchase,On buying the product through my application i can fetch all the information regarding the products in my console, but the problems occurs where i am not getting the pop-up from App Store which shows all the information to buyers. I cannot figure out the problem. Please suggest some solution for this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post some of the code so that we can help

Comment: I was getting the pop up yesterday,but not today even though i have not made any changes in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's IAP backend (test mode) has been up and down over the last 5 days, mostly down, there's been no official confirmation of the outage, just check twitter for similar complaints.

Answer (score -1):

need code.. or follow troy brant's awesome tutorial

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/